# Select number of entries inside a given key for a PostgreSQL JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column with sample content as follows:

```
{"kay1": val1, "myMap": {"UniqueKey1": "UniqueValue1", "UniqueKey2": "UniqueValue2", "UniqueKey3": "UniqueValue3", "UniqueKey4": "UniqueValue4"}, "key2": {"key3": {"key4": "val4"}, "val3": {"key5": "val5"}}
```

I want to find all rows where number of entries in 'myMap' are greater than / equal to / less than some integer -- I have few million of such rows, so it would be helpful if indexing can also be used!

In the example above, there are 4 entries in 'myMap'. So for a query something like "select * from myTable where jsonb_key_length(myJsonbColumn -> 'myMap') = 4" the above row should be returned. [Assuming there is a function jsonb_key_length() that returns length of the given json object]

I found similar question here: [Postgres json key count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998158/postgres-json-key-count/37202624).

But, it requires name of the keys, Can this be done without using key names?

**Solution**

> Thanks @jmelesky for his suggestion.

Following query worked for me:

```
SELECT id, count(elements)
FROM (SELECT id, jsonb_object_keys(column -> 'myMap') AS elements
      FROM myTable GROUP BY id
     ) x
GROUP BY id
```

> Including @jmelesky's suggestion

```
SELECT id, (SELECT count(*)
            FROM (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(a->'myMap')
                  FROM test_json x where x.id = y.id
                  ) z
            ) count
FROM test_json y group by id;
```

> Found another, even faster solution

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_object_keys(column -> 'myMap')), 1) AS count
FROM myTable
```

To use index:
Create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_object_keys_length(_j jsonb)
RETURNS INT LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_object_keys(column -> 'myMap')), 1)';
```

Create index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_myMapCount ON myTable (jsonb_object_keys_length(column -> 'myMap'));
```

Use function in query:

```
SELECT id, jsonb_object_keys_length(column -> 'myMap') AS count
FROM myTable
```

Please do suggest, if there is a better way to model this query. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) called `json_object_keys`, which is probably the key part to this problem. It takes a json object and returns the keys as rows of a relation.

```
=# create table test_json (a json);
CREATE TABLE
=# insert into test_json values ('{"kay1": 1, "myMap": {"UniqueKey1": "UniqueValue1", "UniqueKey2": "UniqueValue2", "UniqueKey3": "UniqueValue3", "UniqueKey4": "UniqueValue4"}, "key2": {"key3": {"key4": "val4"}, "val3": {"key5": "val5"}}}');
INSERT 0 1
=# select json_object_keys(a) from test_json;
 json_object_keys 
------------------
 kay1
 myMap
 key2
(3 rows)
=# select json_object_keys(a->'myMap') from test_json;
 json_object_keys 
------------------
 UniqueKey1
 UniqueKey2
 UniqueKey3
 UniqueKey4
(4 rows)
```

From there, you can just wrap that in a subquery, like so:

```
=# select count(*) from (select json_object_keys(a->'myMap') from test_json) x;
 count 
-------
     4
(1 row)
```

**Edited to add**: There is a jsonb equivalent (`jsonb_object_keys`), which works identically with jsonb values. Sorry, I tend to do my test cases in vanilla json.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, this query does not work as expected as I have multiple rows and I want to find this count for each row.
For eg:
id | column
1  | {"kay1": val1, "myMap": {"UniqueKey1": "UniqueValue1", "UniqueKey2": "UniqueValue2", "UniqueKey3": "UniqueValue3", "UniqueKey4": "UniqueValue4"}, "key2": {"key3": {"key4": "val4"}, "val3": {"key5": "val5"}}
2 | {"kay1": val1, "myMap": {"UniqueKey21": "UniqueValue21", "UniqueKey22": "UniqueValue22"}, "key2": {"key3": {"key4": "val4"}, "val3": {"key5": "val5"}}

I want something like:
id | myMap_count
1 | 4
2 | 2

Comment: Something like this:  

SELECT id, count(elements) FROM
test_json tj, jsonb_each_text(tj.a -> myMap') AS elements
GROUP BY id  

But, using subqueries instead of 'from'

Comment: It's relatively straightforward. Something like `select id, (select count(*) from (select jsonb_object_keys(a->'myMap') from test_json x where x.id = y.id) z) count from test_json y group by id;` should do.